# Is "servo-drive" a generic term when applied to kitchen cabinets/drawers?

Tags: kitchens, terminology

I'm translating a Russian text about a high-tech kitchen, and one sentence goes like this:

> The cabinets are equipped with **servo drives** and will open at a light touch.

The original text says literally "equipped with electrical motors", but I came across the term "servo-drive". Is this term generic, or is there a more widely used generic term for this?

I would avoid a licensed term in favor of a more generic, common one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my mind, servos are typically used in control-gear, not the sort of thing I'd associate with cabinets.

Personally, I'd use something like:

> The cabinets are electrically driven ...

or

> The cabinets have motor drive ...

Answer (score 1):

There is a "Servo Drive" brand of cabinet door and drawer opening system which may be what they are referring to:

[Servo-Drive web site](https://www.blum.com/us/en/products/motion-technologies/servo-drive/overview/)

I suppose that there may be other vendors with similar products, but in some places the actual name, "SERVO-DRIVE" may be a registered trademark by this company.